# $this->input->request_headers() returns empty array

Tags: codeigniter

I'm prototyping an app using CI 3.0 dev.  I have the following code in my Menu controller:

This code is returning nothing

```
 $myHeaders = $this->input->request_headers();
 log_message('info', "Headers..(option1) ", print_r($myHeaders, TRUE));
```

This code is returning the full array

```
 $headers = apache_request_headers();
 log_message('info', 'Headers.. (option2) '.print_r($headers, TRUE));
```

Yet, the input class is (eventually) calling the same apache_ function.  What dumb thing am I missing?

Here's the log:

```
INFO - 2015-02-22 14:45:56 --> Headers..(option1) 
INFO - 2015-02-22 14:45:56 --> Headers.. (option2) Array
(
    [Host] => oap.local
    [Connection] => keep-alive
    [Content-Length] => 0
    [User-Agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36
    [Origin] => chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
    [Content-Type] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    [Accept] => */*
    [Accept-Encoding] => gzip, deflate
    [Accept-Language] => en-US,en;q=0.8
)
```

Here's the entire controller:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Menu extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }


    public function getMenu($menuID)
    {
        log_message('info', __METHOD__ . "MenuID is ", $menuID);

        $myHeaders = $this->input->request_headers();
        log_message('info', "Headers..(option1) ", print_r($myHeaders, TRUE));

        $headers = apache_request_headers();
        log_message('info', 'Headers.. (option2) '.print_r($headers, TRUE));


        $deviceID = $this->input->post('device_reg_id', TRUE);
        log_message('info', "device=".$deviceID);
        $siteID = $this->input->post('site_id', TRUE);
        log_message('info', "device=".$siteID);

        $this->load->helper('zip');
        $this->load->helper('download');
        $filename = '';
        $rc = zipFile('./assets/menu/', $filename);
        $rc = false;
        if ($rc) {
            $data = file_get_contents($filename); // Read the file's contents
            $name = 'menu.zip';            
            force_download($name, $data);
        } else {
            log_message('info', "returning 500");
            $this->output->set_status_header('500');    
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help you out. The log_message function (./system/core/Common.php) takes three parameters. The first being the level (error, debug, or info), the second being the message (string value) and the being a boolean.

In your controller on lines 12, and 15 you are sending menuID as the third parameter and print_r(myHeaders,TRUE). I think you meant to concatinate the values to your message.

Try changing your code to something like this:

```
log_message('info', __METHOD__ . "MenuID is ".$menuID);

$myHeaders = $this->input->request_headers();
log_message('info', "Headers..(option1) ".print_r($myHeaders, TRUE));
```

Comment: Thanks for finding that William.  I knew it had to be some nuff nuff action on my part.